# Jquery Ui is not working in react functional component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jquery-ui, resize

I want to achieve Resizable in React using Jquery UI.

I have code like this..

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui'; 

...
...

useEffect(() => {
    $(function () {
      $(".resizable").resizable();
    });
  }, [])

...
...

<div className="resizable" >Test</div>
```

I dont get the error
but the resizable is not working ...

I want acheive like this [jqueryui.com/resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Comment: Did you tried change the className to class? As jQuery way is targeting the HTML class, as className is not valid in jQuery.

Comment: @TommyTom I think there is no problem with className , it internally converted to class and jquery can target this. my problem is I cant use 'jquery UI ' functionalities like resizable,  selectable inside the react components ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

First, install jquery-ui-bundle

```
npm install jquery-ui-bundle --save
```

Then,

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.css';

...
...
const ref = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    $(function () {
      $(ref.current).resizable();
    });
  }, [ref.current]);

...
...

<div className="resizable" ref={ref}>Test</div>
```

Upon doing some googling I found while using `jquery-ui` we can import individual widgets (could be quite cumbersome) or install `jquery-ui-bundle` instead and import it only once.